# How do you return multiple values based on an if statement in a String type method (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, return

I am working on a part of an assignment that requires me to the compute runners who ran above the average speed (based on 15 runners whose speed/names.. are given in the assignment and I already added all 15 values to the array in the main method).

In the definition class, I have created a method ( which must be type String according to assignment) to compute if runner [i]'s time is =< average speed.

This is my method for finding the above average runners (there are more than one) BUT this method only prints ONE runner when ran in main. How would I allow for MULTIPLE array values to be returned??

Code:

```
// Finding above average:

public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {

    for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {

        if (runners[i].getTime() <= BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners)) {

            String aboveAverage = runners[i].getFirstName() + " " + runners[i].getLastName() + ", Years Competing: "
                    + runners[i].getYears();

            return aboveAverage;

        } // End of if

    } // End of for loop

    return null;

} // End of getAboveAverageRunner method:


} // End of class BanffMarathonRunner:
```

---

Revised :

```
public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {

    ArrayList<String> thoseAbove = new ArrayList <String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {

        if (runners[i].getTime() <= BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners)) {

            String aboveAverage = runners[i].getFirstName() + " " + runners[i].getLastName() + ", Years Competing: "
                    + runners[i].getYears();


            thoseAbove.add(aboveAverage);

            //return aboveAverage;

            // End of if statement:
        }

        // End of for loop:
    }
    return thoseAbove;
```

Now, I get an error on the return thoseAbove

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to String`

I understand the error I just don't know how to fix it while keeping the return type.

Comment: by using a collection or an array and returning this collection or array. Or by combining this collection or array into a single string. The return statement will end the execution of the method.

Comment: Or in a composite Object.

Comment: @KevinEsche do you mind giving me an example of creating a new array ? Would I create it in the definition class? and would my return statement instead be the name of that new array? (new to programming)

Comment: What you assignment says the method have to return? It has to be specified somehow I think... Can you post a link?

Comment: @Betlista
 public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {

is in the assignment "operations" which must be followed when coding.

Answer (score 3):

If it has to return a string then how about returning a pipe delimitered string?

e.g.

```
StringBuilder myList = new StringBuilder ();
for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {

    if (runners[i].getTime() <= BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners)) {

        String aboveAverage = runners[i].getFirstName() + " " + runners[i].getLastName() + ", Years Competing: "
                + runners[i].getYears();

        myList.append (aboveAverage).append ("|");

        // End of if statement:
    }

    // End of for loop:
}
return myList.toString ();  // maybe remove the trailing pipe
```

Then in your calling method you can use `String.split ("\\|")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just a bit confused, would the code you suggested be inside the "public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {" method?

and what is a pipe delimitered string?

Comment: Yes, this would replace your code in your method.  A pipe is `|` - a comma  is commonly used to delimit records, but as you have `commas` in your data, then another suitable character needs to be found e.g. a pipe.

Comment: Okay thank you. One more thing, is what you suggested an array list? I think that is what I need. I havent covered delimitered pipes or seen anything like String.split("\\ |") yet in my course so I am concerned the prof may be looking for something more simple. @ScaryWombat

Comment: Of course if you could return a List then that would be better, but as you can't I am suggesting some very standard and basic java

Comment: There are no requirements regarding what I can return, only that the method type must be String. If I returned null outside the for loop and returned the arraylist inside would that work? @ScaryWombat

Comment: what does `only that the method type must be String.` mean?

Comment: Instead of my StringBuilder, you could use a ArrayList and return that.

Comment: on the assignment the prof included "attributes" and "operations" that are to be followed. Under "operations" one of the methods the prof listed is
"public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) "

Comment: In that case, my answer is perfect ;-)

Comment: So, for the rest of the assignment I have followed the methods as declared by the prof and everything has worked well. That is why I believe the method must remain as stated.

Comment: I added revised version of the code with the suggestions you gave me, I used ArrayList instead as I was more familliar with that, I have never seen StringBuilder before ( although it seems this may work better). I am getting an error on the append line. What does this line mean?

Comment: In that case you want to do `thoseAbove.add (aboveAverage);`  But your assignment says you must return a String, so my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're stopping at the first runner that qualifies and returning that. Instead you need to somehow collect *all* runners that qualify.

You probably want to return a `List<String>` rather than a `String`. Fortunately, java 8 can help here:

```
public static List<String> getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {
    int averageTime = BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners);

    return Arrays.stream(runners).filter(r -> r.getTime() < average)
      .map(r -> r.getFirstName() + " " + r.getLastName() + ", Years Competing: " + r.getYears())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you absolutely must return a single `String` value (not recommended), then join them with semi-colons (or whatever you like):

```
public static List<String> getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {
    int averageTime = BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners);

    return Arrays.stream(runners).filter(r -> r.getTime() < average)
      .map(r -> r.getFirstName() + " " + r.getLastName() + ", Years Competing: " + r.getYears())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "\"", "\""));
}
```

Note: this will return a csv of quoted values, like `"John Smith ...", "Bob Brown ...", ...`. The quotes are added in case the data contains a comma.

Better yet would be to return a `List<Runner>`, and *render* them *elsewhere* as you need:

```
public static List<Runner> getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {
    int averageTime = BanffMarathonRunner.getAverageTime(runners);

    return Arrays.stream(runners).filter(r -> r.getTime() < average)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: and what about "...which must be type String according to assignment..." ?

Comment: `which must be type String according to assignment`

Comment: public static String getAboveAverageRunners(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners) {

^ this line must remain as is and I am to code around it, So, I think the list <runner>  would still work right? or must it be the type? @Bohemian